# Delete specific Node in Linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list like this

```
struct product {
string ID;
double quantity;
product* next = NULL;
};
```

And I want to delete all products with quantity less than a number.
This function returns true if at least one product are deleted, otherwise returns false. Here is my code

```
bool deleteProducts(product*& pHead, double quantity) {
    static int flag = 0;
    product* pTemp = pHead;
    product* prev = pHead;
    if (pTemp != NULL && pTemp->quantity <= quantity) pHead = pTemp->next;
    while (pTemp != NULL && pTemp->quantity > quantity) {
        prev = pTemp;
        pTemp = pTemp->next;
    }
    if (pTemp == NULL) return flag;
    flag = 1;
    prev->next = pTemp->next;
    deleteProducts(prev->next, quantity);
}
```

But when I have a list (quantities only) like this:

```
7 -> 7.5 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6
```

And I run the function with quantity = 10, it return:

```
7.5 -> 5
```

It's not true, can anybody explain for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is `flag` static? Once you have deleted one node, the function will always return `true`.

Comment: @molbdnilo cause after every recursive loop flag will be 0 although there's deleted node

Comment: It's `static`, so it's only initialised once, which is the first time the function is called.

Comment: What made you use recursion here. Removing elements in LList is always O(n). Just traverse the list and delete that matches the delete condition.

Comment: To debug it, sit down with a pad of paper and a pencil and draw your list and all the pointers. This is the best method for debugging pointer-oriented algorithms and structures.

Comment: Thank you you guys so much, I will try another way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has several issues.

1. You're using a static `flag`. (See the other comments to know why it's bad.)
2. You're using recursion. 
   Since you're using a static flag, it screws up the recursion.
3. You can delete the element while iterating itself, then the runtime would be O(n).
4. You can use a doubly linked-list to avoid using the `pPrev` in the loop.

Here is the proper solution I came up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct product {
    string ID;
    double quantity;
    product* next = NULL;
} product;

product* deleteProducts(product*& pHead, double quantity) {
    product* pTemp = pHead;
    product* pPrev = pHead;

    while (pTemp != NULL) {
        if ( pTemp->quantity > quantity ){
            if ( pTemp == pHead ){
                cout << "Deleteing Current Head " <<  pTemp->quantity << endl;
                product* pTmp = pHead;
                pTemp = pTemp->next;
                pHead = pPrev = pTemp;
                delete pTmp;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Deleteing Node" <<  pTemp->quantity << endl;
                product* pNext = pTemp->next;
                delete pTemp;
                pTemp = pNext;
                pPrev->next = pTemp;
            }
        }
        else{        
            pPrev = pTemp;
            pTemp = pTemp->next;
        }
    }

    return pHead;
}

bool printProducts(product*& pHead) {
    product* pTemp = pHead;

    while (pTemp != NULL) {
        cout << pTemp->quantity << " ";
        pTemp = pTemp->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
   product* p1 = new product{"1", 7};
   product* p2 = new product{"2", 7.5};
   product* p3 = new product{"3", 2};
   product* p4 = new product{"4", 5};
   product* p5 = new product{"5", 6};

   p1->next = p2;
   p2->next = p3;
   p3->next = p4;
   p4->next = p5;

   if ( deleteProducts(p1, 10) ){
       cout << "Done" << endl;
   }

   printProducts(p1);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting state short-circuits list onto `pHead`, setting local `prev` to address of pHead. Why not use `pHead ->prev`  or `nullptr`?

And removing elements from doubly linked  list is operation with time compexity O(n) operation. You have to walk through list and collapse those records that match your criteria.